# CSS selector is selecting all p elements in page

Tags: html, css

I have a page and I want to style all the `<p>` elements inside a class. The problem is that, instead styling only the selected `<p>`, it's styling all the `<p>` elements in the page. I didn't find any open tags, so I don't know what's going on. Here's the commented codes:

```css
#mainTips {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.dicas {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

/* Here's where i'm styling the elements */

.dicas h3,
p {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ecf0f1;

}

.dicas p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-top: 6.5em;
}

.dicas:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-image: url("../img/tip1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.dicas:nth-of-type(2) {

  background-image: url("../img/tip2.jpg");

  background-size: cover;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

#othTips {

  margin-top: 1em;

  width: 100%;

}

#othTips img {

  float: left;

  margin-left: 2em;

  width: 9.5em;

  height: 10em;

  margin-bottom: 3em;

}

.description {

  position: absolute;

  background-color: #2980b9;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Rebecca Bueno</title>
  <!-- Chamando o CSS e as fontes do Google -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/dicas.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/media.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/animations.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Rebecca Bueno</h1>

  <div id="menu">
    <!-- Início menu -->
    <ul>
      <a href="index.html">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="tend.html">
        <li>Tendências</li>
      </a>
      <a href="dicas.html">
        <li>Dicas</li>
      </a>
      <a href="contato.html">
        <li>Contato</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Fim menu -->

  <!-- I want to style only that p element. -->
  <div id="mainTips">
    <section class="dicas">
      <article>
        <h3> Dicas para... </h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div id="othTips">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/bg2.jpg" />
    </a>
    <!-- But it's also styling here -->
    <div class="description">
      <p>Descrição da dica</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/bg2.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/othtm2.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/othtm2.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/tm4.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/tm4.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <!-- Rodapé -->

  </div>
</body>

<!-- Chamando o JavaScript -->
<script src="js/styles.js"></script>
<script src="js/pgMan.js"></script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    carregaFundo("bg");
    slideImg();
    lgSld(["Teste da legenda da primeira imagem.",
      "Teste da legenda da segunda imagem.",
      "Teste da legenda da terceira imagem.",
      "Teste da legenda da quarta imagem."
    ]);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it me or is there only one `<p>` element anyway?

Comment: Two <p>, but I don't understand the problem...

Comment: `.dicas h3,p` selects ***all*** p elements, just as specified by your selector.

Comment: Hmm... I created a JSFiddle, but I can't see a clear result. Use .dicas p{} and .description p{}

Comment: So this is the problem? That error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of `.dicas h3,p{...}` you may have meant to use:

```
.dicas h3, .dicas p {
     ...
}
```

The former does indeed select all `p`s, since commas effectively "reset" the selection route.

Answer (score 1):

`.dicas h3,p` means `.dicas h3` **or** `p`. The comma groups otherwise complete selectors including combinators, not just the nearest parts that don't include combinators.

You need to specify `.dicas` and use a descendant combinator for each part.

```
.dicas h3,
.dicas p {

}
```

Answer (score -3):

You should use `div > p{}` to select all direct childs from the div. So, all divs which have `<p>` inside will take a certain style.

Comment: "from the div" - from ***all*** divs. Also, this does not add anything useful to the question as the correct answer has already been given twice.

Comment: this will only select first child, i mean to say it will only select immediate p or h3 tag after the .dicas class